# What's the necessity of string in c++ while we already have char[]?

Tags: c++

Many topics have discussed the difference between string and char[]. However, they are not clear to me to understand why we need to bring string in c++? Any insight is welcome, thanks!

Comment: If you've read about the differences, then it should be clear that `std::string` offers a lot more functionality than `char[]`.

Comment: Because it's easier to work with for people lacking a concrete foundation on things like memory management and operations like concatenations etc

Comment: You may as well ask _Why do we need to bring classes in C++?_ Simply said, life is much easier with them.

Comment: try adding two `char[]`s together, a nice class interface can go a long way

Comment: Try writing non-trivial code that does multiple operations (copying, appending, reallocating, etc) on several strings that are each represented as an array of `char`, and you'll find you write a fair amount of code and then spend lots of time getting it working right for every string and for every operation involving multiple strings (appending, etc). Then write code (from scratch, not trying to "adapt" the array based code) that instead uses `std::string` to do the same set of things - you'll find you write a smaller amount of code, and spend less time tracking down bugs to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char[]` is C style. It is not object oriented, it forces you as the programmer to deal with implementation details (such as '\0' terminator) and rewrite standard code for handling strings every time over and over.

`char[]` is just an array of bytes, which can be used to store a string, but it is not a string in any meaningful way.

`std::string` is a class that properly represents a string and handles all string operations.
It lets you create objects and keep your code fully OOP (if that is what you want).
More importantly, it takes care of memory management for you.

Consider this simple piece of code:

```
// extract to string
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

main ()
{
    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

How would you write the same thing using `char[]`?
Assume you can not know in advance how long the name would be!

Same goes for string concatenation and other operations.
With real string represented as `std::string` you combine two strings with a simple += operator. One line.

If you are using `char[]` however, you need to do the following:

1. Calculate the size of the combined string + terminator character.
2. Allocate memory for the new combined string.
3. Use `strncpy` to copy first string to new array.
4. Use `strncat` to append second string to first string in new array.

Plus, you need to remember not to use the unsafe `strcpy` and `strcat` and to free the memory once you are done with the new string.

`std::string` saves you all that hassle and the many bugs you can introduce while writing it.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by MSalters in a comment, strings can grow. This is, in my opinion, the strongest reason to have them in C++.

For example, the following code has a bug which may cause it to crash, or worse, to appear to work correctly:

```
char message[] = "Hello";
strcat(message, "World");
```

The same idea with `std::string` behaves correctly:

```
std::string message{"Hello"};
message += "World";
```

---

Additional benefits of `std::string`:

1. You can send it to functions by value, while `char[]` can only be sent by reference; this point looks rather insignificant, but it enables powerful code like `std::vector<std::string>` (a list of strings which you can add to)
2. `std::string` stores its length, so any operation which needs the length is more efficient
3. `std::string` works similarly to all other C++ containers (`vector`, etc) so if you are already familiar with containers, `std::string` is easy to use
4. `std::string` has overloaded comparison operators, so it's easy to use with `std::map`, `std::sort`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

String class is no more than an amelioration of the `char[]` variable.
With strings you can achieve the same goals than the use of a `char[]` variable, but you won't have to matter about little tricks of `char[]` like pointers, segmentation faults...
This is a more convenient way to build strings, but you don't really see the "undergrounds" of the language, like how to implement concatenation or length functions... 
Here is the documentation of the `std::string` class in C++ : [C++ string documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: There's not really a `char[]` type, in C++ arrays have fixed sizes. But strings can grow